# Can 70% vinegar be used as a solder flux in emergencies?

Tags: soldering, flux

I wonder if I can use 70% vinegar in place of a solder flux for emergency repairs.

Comment: Does it even work? If it does, then I guess you can decide for yourself if vinegar on your electronics is acceptable in an emergency (I guess it would be). (And if it doesnt work I guess there is no point asking..)

Comment: Where does one even obtain 70% vinegar? Would you distill it from the 5% stuff?

Comment: Also if you live where pines grow, maybe you could harvest the resin and use that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resin_acid

Comment: Virtually all solder "wire" you'll find commercially will have flux built in.   What are you using that doesn't have flux?

Comment: probably plumbing

Comment: I can buy 70% vinegar in a local supermarket.

Comment: Vinegar is a solution of about 5 to 8 percent acetic acid. 70 percent vinegar, what is that? I am sure you cannot buy 70 percent acetic acid in the supermarket. It is a pretty corrosive substance. I would be hesitant to put it on a PCB, and if I did, I would  want to wash it with copious amounts of water afterwards.

Comment: I've got a bottle of 70% acetic acid vinegar downstairs right now.  I bought it in a grocery store here in Germany.

Comment: We also have technical grade acetic acid (70%) here, too. I order it online. (I don't think grocers in the US carry it.) I use it, with boiling hot water, to clean drain pipes and buckets with heavy crystaline 'crud'. (I think @jsotola has it right.) I had to squelch my old 'goto cleaner' using 100% sulfuric acid and potassium dichromate (which can be used to any temp before the H2SO4 starts to boil at around 315 C.) That doesn't work so well when there's water involved. Or PVC at these concentrations ;) Hmm. Or skin or meat, come to think of it.

Comment: For hobbyist/emergency repair, external flux is mostly an optional tool. It is only used when doing professional soldering. You'd use it when working with fine pitch SMD and similar. For "emergency repairs" I don't see why the rosin core flux in your solder wire wouldn't be sufficient. I often use it when soldering quick & dirty lab boards, like: oxidated/polluted surface, cover with solder, remove solder with wick braid, then do the actual soldering. Now if you bought some plumbing solder from Alibaba, then that is another problem...

Comment: Seems like it is just confusion over nomenclature. To me, 70 percent acetic acid is not vinegar. Vinegar is a solution of about 4 percent acetic acid manufactured through fermentation. Vinegar is edible. I would not say that "vinegar" and "acetic acid" can be used interchangeably as JRE is doing. I am surprised you can buy 70 percent acetic acid in the supermarket, but I believe you. I have only ever seen it in chemistry labs and it was handled with care.

Answer (score 1):

Flux uses [acid activators](https://www.chemtronics.com/essential-guide-to-flux-for-soldering-electronics) that reduces the oxide layer on solder which reduces the thermal conductivity while using a hand iron and also prevents the solder from melting.

Vinegar is an acid, but there are no other halogens in it, so it's likely to not be that effective. I don't think it would reduce the oxide layer much and seeing as how its produced by oxidizing ethanol. In addition if you did get it hot, seeing as how it's an organic compound, it would probably form a nasty carbon layer and make things worse.

I suppose you could experiment with it. I wouldn't suggest using it for anything reasonable.